# Need a piece of advice on OO JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm pretty new in oriented object JS and I was wondering if there was a better  way to do this :

```
this.aProperty = function(myCurrentInstance){ some code }(this);
```

I just want a property of my object to get a value returned by a function, but this function needs to use others properties of the current object so I have to give the function the object itself.

However, is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: if the function modify and use the object, why it's not a method of this object ?

Comment: basically, this property will never change, so it owuld be a 1 time call, this is why I don't want to make a specific function to do this, but rather use an anonym function.

Comment: If it's gonna happen just one time, you can use `.call` or `.apply` to force scope.

Comment: so you can add code directly in the constructor if it's called when object is created.
If you want call the function later, using `call` is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Function scope is one of the tougher problems in OOJS! The key is to remember that an object method is just a *function assigned as a property of an object*, and so if it's not called carefully (e.g. it's passed as a callback to something) then it can be run in the wrong context, with the wrong thing bound to `this`, as you're discovering.

Remember that:

```
var someObj = {
    someMethod: function() {

    }
}

someObj.someMethod(); // in someMethod, this will be someObj

var someRef = someObj.someMethod;
someRef(); // the function will now run with this bound to the window object, which you probably don't want
```

If you have to pass a reference, you can *bind* the function. In modern browsers, you can use `Function.prototype.bind`:

```
this.aProperty = (function() {}).bind(this);
```

Older browsers will require a polyfill. jQuery has one:

```
this.aProperty = $.proxy(function() {    }, this);
```

Or you can write your own:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(scope) {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        fn.apply(scope, arguments);
    }
}
```

and then use the `.bind` syntax like the first example.